# Understanding then() in Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I am reading through the documentation in Cypress and I think I have an idea as to what then() does.  It works like promises, where a promise returns another promise, but with then(), we are returning a new subject.

If we look at the code example below, we are using then() because we are returning a new variable, which in this case is called target.

Am I understanding this correctly?  If not, can someone correct me?

```
  it.only('Marks an incomplete item complete', () => {
         //we'll need a route to stub the api call that updates our item
         cy.fixture('todos')
         .then(todos => {
             //target is a single todo, taken from the head of the array. We can use this to define our route
             const target = Cypress._.head(todos)
             cy.route(
                 "PUT",
                 `api/todos/${target.id}`,
                 //Here we are mergin original item with an object literal 
                 Cypress._.merge(target, {isComplete: true})
             )
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

`.then` is used to receive the results from `cy.fixture('todos')`. The variable `target` is not significant in this code.

In your code sample, the variable that is returned from `cy.fixture` is named `todos` - the spacing of the code may be throwing you off here? The `.then` call is attached to the `cy.fixture()` call

```
// These 2 code blocks are the same - just different spacing
cy.fixture('todos')
.then(todos => {});

cy.fixture('todos').then(todos => {});
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Usage

```
cy.fixture('logo.png').then((logo) => {
  // load data from logo.png
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .then() allows you to use the yielded subject in a callback function and should be used when you need to manipulate some values or do some actions.

To put it simply, it is used to play around with the yield of the previous command and work around with it in that case. THEN() command is handy and helpful in debugging the yield of the previous command.

```
  const baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

   describe("Get Call-Expect+ normal req", () => {
   it("GetPostById-Expect", () => {
     cy.request(baseURL + "/posts/1").as("GetPostById");
     cy.get("@GetPostById").then((response) => {
      //response: status
     expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
     expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
         });
   });
```

Refer: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then#Promises